# Error in compilation while trying to write a program on bubble sort using pointers

Tags: c, sorting, pointers

I tried my hand in writing a program in C to "bubble sort" a sequence of numbers, obtained as input, using pointers. It was as follows:

```
#include<stdio.h>
void swap(int *p,int *q)
{
  int t;
  t=*p;
  *p=*q;
  *q=t;
}
void sort(int *a[],int n)
{
  int i,j;
  for(i=0;i<n-1;i++)
  {
    for(j=0;j<n-i-1;j++)
    {
      if(a[j]>a[j+1])
      swap(a[j],a[j+1]);
    }
  }
}      
int main()
{
  int p[40],b,i;
  printf("Enter the number of elements in the sequence: \n");
  scanf("%d",&b);
  printf("Enter the elements of the sequence: \n");
  for(i=0;i<b;i++)
  {
    scanf("%d",p[i]);
  }
  sort(p,b);
  printf("The sorted sequence is: \n");
  for(i=0;i<b;i++)
  {
    printf("%d \n",p[i]);
  }
  return 0;
}
```

However, the program did not compile. It showed the following error message:

[image]

The error message shows:

```
error 139 - Argument no 1 of 'sort' must be of type '<ptr><ptr>int', not 'int[40]'
```

Can anybody tell me how I should correct my program so that it gets compiled and gives a correct output?

**ADDENDUM:** The following is the corrected code, as asked for-

```
#include<stdio.h>
void myswap(int *p,int *q)
{
  int t;
  t=*p;
  *p=*q;
  *q=t;
}
void sort(int a[],int n)
{
  int i,j;
  for(i=0;i<n-1;i++)
  {
    for(j=0;j<n-i-1;j++)
    {
      if(a[j]>a[j+1])
      myswap(&a[j],&a[j+1]);
    }
  }
}      
int main()
{
  int p[40],b,i;
  printf("Enter the number of elements in the sequence: \n");
  scanf("%d",&b);
  printf("Enter the elements of the sequence: \n");
  for(i=0;i<b;i++)
  {
    scanf("%d",&p[i]);
  }
  sort(p,b);
  printf("The sorted sequence is: \n");
  for(i=0;i<b;i++)
  {
    printf("%d \n",p[i]);
  }
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: You declare that the first argument to `sort` is an array of pointers to `int`, but then you pass a pointer to `int` when you call it (remember that arrays naturally decays to pointers to their first element). Those two types are not similar in any way.

Comment: Pass &p[i] to scanf.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Thanks. I corrected it. But the compiler shows the same error again.

Comment: Your image is unreadable on a cell phone — one more reason people don't like embedded images in questions.  Please embed the text of the error messages directly in the question, as 'code' (indented, in other words).

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Okay. Correcting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From a short look two mistakes found:

```
void sort(int *a[],int n)
```

should be

```
void sort(int a[],int n)
```

and

```
swap(a[j],a[j+1])
```

should be

```
swap(&a[j],&a[j+1])
```

`a[j]` is just an integer you need to take the address of the element placing `&` since swap declaration requires pointers.

Comment: Thanks! The program is running now.. But can you tell me what the error actually meant? And why are the things stated above wrong?

Comment: The error said "you're passing an `int` and you need to pass an `int *`".  Your code passed an `int` (`a[i]`, for example), but you should have been passing an `int *` (`&a[i]`, for example).  The `scanf()` problem probably wasn't being identified for you, but was actually the same problem — you were passing an `int` where `scanf()` expects an `int *`.

Comment: I don't know the lines of your program, but I think first mistake had to do with @Jonathan Leffler comment ,the other says that you pass <ptr><ptr> to int, in the case where you declare `void sort(int *a[],int n)' but you only pass a which is <ptr> to int. When you want to pass an array a to a function then the function declaration should be like `a[]` which indicates an array of unknown size or just `*a` since array in this case is like a pointer...

Comment: @coder Yes, `by a`, I meant `a[ ]`.But, like you said, I tried putting `a[ ] in place of a` when I use the `sort` function. Still it gives the same error.

Comment: Could you edit an give us your final (changed ) code?

Comment: @coder Seems quite mysterious to me as how this works perfectly, although my sort function has no pointer as its argument. How does this function then make changes to my original array `p`? Its argument is some different array `a`.

Comment: First of all I asked the edited code since you said previously `Still it gives the same error` but based to your new comments i suppose that code now is correct . To answer to your question, `YES YOU PASS A POINTER` ,because you pass to sort the array p but array is like a pointer pointing to the first element so any  change done in the function always affects the array elements!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/146288/discussion-between-schrodingerscat-and-coder).